# asp.net is there a way to trigger Session_End like event when cookie expires?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

hope this is not a too basic of a question. I was wondering just like Session_end event is triggered when a session is expired, is there a way when using formsauthentication and a cookie expires then is there any event that is triggered? Or is there a possibility to find out when a cookie has expired (not when a new request is made) and then take custom actions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to know this. We use to do this JavaScript hack at the master page. Please note that are setting the cookieExpiryTime manually.

```
var timeoutID,
    cookieExpiryTime = 20 * 60 * 60; //20 minutes
function HandleSessionExpiry() {
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/Login.aspx?action=logout';
    }, cookieExpiryTime);
}

window.onload = HandleSessionExpiry;
```

This works fine if the page is not making any AJAX request, but is there are AJAX requests, we need to write two functions on global ajaxStart and ajaxStop. ( Using jQuery here for this )

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    HandleSessionExpiry();
});
```

And the Page_Load of Login.aspx we did this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if(! String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["!action"]) 
            && Request.QueryString["!action"] == "logout")
        {
            Session.Abandon();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is extremely ugly hack. Its much better to do an Ajax call to know if the session has expired.

Comment: @Aniket, I would like to see that code. setInterval seems the only way for me. are you suggesting using a setTimeout call every second to make an ajax call to check if the session has expired?

Comment: I was suggesting extending or hooking `__doPostBack` to check if the session has expired BEFORE initiating the actual postback.

Comment: yeah i read another hack on writing it on render page. doesnt seem to work though on ajax calls

Comment: But this is a problem with Inproc sessions only. Some SessionState providers, IIRC Microsoft Azure SessionState provider based on Azure Cache seems to allow sliding expiration.